# LUKS encrypted drive is missing. "cryptsetup: lvm is not available"

Tags: kernel, boot, lvm, luks, disk-encryption

I have an internal SSD (NVMe) on which I've installed Ubuntu 18.04 with Full Encryption using LUKS. Recently, I replaced the motherboard of my laptop which caused the signature verification of the kernel to get failed during boot.

```
error: /boot/vmlinuz-****-generic has invalid signature
error: you need to load the kernel first
```

If I tried to boot without secure boot then it gets past the signature verification, but later during boot process, I get an error that says "cryptsetup: lvm is not available".

So, in order to fix the signature verification issue that occurs with secure boot, I read that I need to add a newly signed kernel into the boot partition using a live USB. However, after booting into the Live OS (Ubuntu) I couldn't find the NVMe drive at all. I checked the `/dev` location and used several tools such as `gparted`, `fdisk`, `lsblk`. I just couldn't get the drive listed with any of these tools.

May I know why the drive is not getting detected? And how to get this drive mounted? I am also not sure why the "cryptsetup: lvm is not available" issue occurs.

PS: I tried booting up WindowsToGo (Windows 10) and from it, I was able to find the SSD drive being listed under "Disk Management" utility. So, I don't think it is an issue with the SSD. It is functional. I am just not able to get this drive listed with Live Linux.

Comment: anything in dmesg? e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/470778

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed the issue.

The issue occurred since the BIOS settings of SATA Operation was defaulted to `RAID On` mode instead of `AHCI` mode, with the newly replaced motherboard.

So, basically changing the SATA Operation to AHCI and then disabling Secure Boot(to get rid of Invalid Kernel Signature) fixed the issue.