# What "nvme: missing or invalid SUBNQN field" means and how should I fix it?

Tags: nvme

I found this in my kernel logs:

```
kernel: nvme nvme0: missing or invalid SUBNQN field.
```

What does it mean and how should I fix it?

```bsh
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.04
Release:        21.04
Codename:       hirsute
```

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/470778/nvme-missing-or-invalid-subnqn-field